# Multiple hatched areas with different hatch color using pcolor in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to change the hatch color of a hatched area but nothing seems to be working.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap

x_range = np.linspace(0, 1, 30)
y_range = np.linspace(0, 1, 30)

Z = np.zeros([30, 30])

Z[:10, :] += -1
Z[-10:, :] += 1

fig, ax = plt.subplots(constrained_layout = True)

cond1 = (Z != -1)
mZ1 = np.ma.array(Z, mask=cond1)
gains_map = ListedColormap(['gainsboro'])
col1 = ax.pcolor(x_range, y_range, mZ1, cmap = gains_map)
hatch1 = ax.pcolor(x_range, y_range, mZ1,
                hatch = '\\ \\',  zorder = 2, alpha = 0)

cond2 = (Z != 1)
mZ2 = np.ma.array(Z, mask=cond2)
coral_map = ListedColormap(['lightcoral'])
col2 = ax.pcolor(x_range, y_range, mZ2, cmap = coral_map)
hatch2 = ax.pcolor(x_range, y_range, mZ2,
                hatch = '\\ \\', edgecolor = 'chocolate', zorder = 2, alpha = 0)
```

In this example I'd like the hatches of the red area to be a color other than black (but not affect the color of the hatches in the gray area). The areas are rectangular here, so other solutions would be possible, but I'd like something that works for more complex areas created by the mask as well. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why is the transparency set to 0? Try changing it to `alpha=0.4`.

Comment: The reason is that if alpha is set to non-zero, the masked area will be filled in by the default cmap, there seems to be no way to turn this off. Setting alpha to zero does not affect the edges (to which the hatches supposedly belong).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Things to try:

- use a ListedColormap with `'none'` as color to make the facecolor invisible
- use a linewidth of zero to suppress the lines between the cells

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap

x_range = np.linspace(0, 1, 31)
y_range = np.linspace(0, 1, 31)

Z = np.zeros([30, 30])

Z[:10, :] += -1
Z[-10:, :] += 1

fig, ax = plt.subplots(constrained_layout=True)

cond1 = (Z != -1)
mZ1 = np.ma.array(Z, mask=cond1)
gains_map = ListedColormap(['gainsboro'])
none_map = ListedColormap(['none'])
col1 = ax.pcolor(x_range, y_range, mZ1, cmap=gains_map)
hatch1 = ax.pcolor(x_range, y_range, mZ1, cmap=none_map,
                   hatch='\\ \\', edgecolor='red', lw=0, zorder=2)

cond2 = (Z != 1)
mZ2 = np.ma.array(Z, mask=cond2)
coral_map = ListedColormap(['lightcoral'])
col2 = ax.pcolor(x_range, y_range, mZ2, cmap=coral_map)
hatch2 = ax.pcolor(x_range, y_range, mZ2, cmap=none_map,
                   hatch='\\ \\', edgecolor='green', lw=0, zorder=2)
plt.show()
```

[image: multiple areas with different hatch color]

Comment: Thanks JohanC, the suggestion of using a ListedColormap with `'none'` works perfectly! 
I'm totally unclear on why one has to use such an unstraightforward implementation though. This also applies to having to make a ListedColormap with a single color just to display all values the Z array in the same color, as opposed to simply being able to pass a color argument instead of a cmap.

Comment: Probably `pcolor` wasn't designed originally to work with just one color nor to use hatching (and initially probably without masked arrays).  PS: note that you need 31 x-values and 31 y-values for 30x30 cells. The x and y-values determine the borders of the cells.